# Intuition for generalized complex exponentials (like $i^i$)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I understand complex exponential function $e^z$ and its geometric meaning, but when we expand complex exponentiation to $z^w$ for arbitrary complex z and w, $z \neq 0$, I have no intuition what that represents.
Are we doing this just to expand familiar real operations and functions to complex plane or is there some geometric or physical meaning behind it?

Answer (score 4):

Arbitrary exponentiation doesn't exists. What you want to define here is $$ z^w = e^{w \log z}$$

But $\log z$ cannot be defined with consistence on $\mathbb C$.

Conclusion : if you want to understand $z^w$, you must understand how a complex logarithm can be defined and what is means.

Comment: Yes, I know all about complex logarithm troubles, branches and all that. I want to know are there some specific uses of this. Why bother with to introduce this?

Comment: In which context did you see this $z^w$ ?

Comment: In my Complex Analysis class. Yes, we defined it using complex logarithm. We discussed cases when w is natural/rational/irrational. So yes, I have a proper theoretical background about it, I didn't just ran into this expression clueless.
But all we did before this (exponential function!) had a nice geometric/visual explanation, and I'm asking for it for this too... if it exists.